# Error reading from an IP-Camera

Tags: eclipse, javacv, opencv3.0

I capture the image from an IP-Camera and I work with the frames. My programm reads when there is a movement, and then, it makes a photo and save it on the computer. 
It works perfectly at first, but when it is running like 2-3 hours, it usually get an error, and I do not find a explanation for this. Because, if it is an error on getting the image or the processing, it should happens since first, shouldn't it?

The error I get is the next:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.googlecode.javacv.IPCameraFrameGrabber.grab(IPCameraFrameGrabber.java:105)
>       at Llamada.main(Llamada.java:34)

I have looked for the error nº105 but I have not found anything.

The program is the next:

```
public class Llamada {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    IPCameraFrameGrabber grabber = new IPCameraFrameGrabber("http://192.168.2.102:80/mjpg/video.mjpg");
    //OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
    grabber.start();

    IplImage frame = grabber.grab();
    IplImage image = null;
    IplImage prevImage = null;
    IplImage diff = null;

    Date data = new Date();
    String output = "";

    int i=0, j=0;

    CanvasFrame canvasFrame = new CanvasFrame("IP Camera");
    canvasFrame.setCanvasSize(frame.width(), frame.height());

    CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

    while (canvasFrame.isVisible() && (frame = grabber.grab()) != null) {
        cvSmooth(frame, frame, CV_GAUSSIAN, 9, 9, 2, 2);
        if (image == null) {
            image = IplImage.create(frame.width(), frame.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
            cvCvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        } else {
            prevImage = IplImage.create(frame.width(), frame.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
            prevImage = image;
            image = IplImage.create(frame.width(), frame.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
            cvCvtColor(frame, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        }

        if (diff == null) {
            diff = IplImage.create(frame.width(), frame.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        }

        if (prevImage != null) {
            // perform ABS difference
            cvAbsDiff(image, prevImage, diff);
            // do some threshold for wipe away useless details
            cvThreshold(diff, diff, 64, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

            canvasFrame.showImage(diff);

            // recognize contours
            CvSeq contour = new CvSeq(null);
            cvFindContours(diff, storage, contour, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);



            while (contour != null && !contour.isNull()) {
                if (contour.elem_size() > 0) {

                    output = data.toString();

                    if (data != null)
                        output = output.substring(0,10);

                    if(i%300 == 0)
                         cvSaveImage((j++)+" "+ output +"-capture.jpg", frame);


                    CvBox2D box = cvMinAreaRect2(contour, storage);
                    // test intersection
                    if (box != null) {
                        CvPoint2D32f center = box.center();
                        CvSize2D32f size = box.size();

                    }
                    i++;
                }
                contour = contour.h_next();
            }
        }
    }
    grabber.stop();
    canvasFrame.dispose();
}
}
```

Thank you for everything!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a debugger and setting a break point? I understand that waiting around for 2-3 hours isn't fun, but maybe it'd help you get a handle on what's going on.

That seems to be in your `while` loop's second conditional part. Something inside the method `grab` on the `grabber` object is throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Probably the way you've initialized the grabber has led it to do this.

And it would be useful to know which version of the IPCameraFrameGrabber class you're using and what the author of that class really expected. Namely it's initialized to respond to a particular camera's url. In reading the [class](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/IPCameraFrameGrabber.java?r=0e399872bfeb3824e975b3c575ad3a0a41027dee), it would appear this makes no claim to work with all IP cameras' MJPEG streams.

Let's look at one example comment in there:

```
foscam url http://host/videostream.cgi?user=username&pwd=password
           http://192.168.0.59:60/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=password
android ipcam http://192.168.0.57:8080/videofeed
```

And compare that to your url:

```
http://192.168.2.102:80/mjpg/video.mjpg
```

I gather it is not a foscam videostream.cgi url nor an android ipcam videofeed url, which would appear to be the only tested urls. It reminds me of an Axis camera url. More on that later.

In a [recent version](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/IPCameraFrameGrabber.java#L145) of that class (also in the older one actually), there seems to be some hackish attempt at reading only to the end of a subheader that is always delimited by <kbd>cr</kbd><kbd>lf</kbd><kbd>cr</kbd><kbd>lf</kbd> which could have been done just as well with a buffered input reader reading lines until it gets an empty line. What I do see here that seems likely to cause an npe is:

- When your url's http server's response does not contain the `content-length` header, which is quite possible, the returned `readImage()` `byte[]` [is `null`](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/IPCameraFrameGrabber.java#L172).

Since `javax.imageio.ImageIO` specifies that it will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when it gets a `null` input, I'm guessing it's the `ByteArrayInputStream` constructor in the `grabBufferedImage` method that's throwing this, the [`IplImage.createFrom(null)` in the old version](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/IPCameraFrameGrabber.java?r=0e399872bfeb3824e975b3c575ad3a0a41027dee#98), or the [`b.length` in the newer version](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/IPCameraFrameGrabber.java#L121) that is.

None of the line numbers of these versions line up with the error message you've shown that you're getting, so maybe your version of the library is yet again different, and broken differently. Try using the debugger, edit and patch the source of the `IPCameraFrameGrabber` to better support your mjpeg over http "device" based on what you find out is really in the input stream of the http response.

Since the url format reminds me of an Axis camera, I tried this with one running firmware v5.50 with the boa server built in:

```
$ curl -I http://user:pass@10.10.10.10:8080/mjpg/video.mjpg
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=myboundary
```

So you can see the content length is missing there. However, you do say you're getting frames initially for hours, then then, so I'm kind of at a loss with that part. I mean it sounds as though EITHER the input stream is getting closed, or the java implementation wrapping the stream, implemented in the http protocol handler, runs out of some kind of total space or open connection timer for some reason. I know this seems vague.

Another thing that seems odd is that from what I read in the two example classes of `IPCameraFrameGrabber` linked, every call to grab reads the input stream looking for headers first, which doesn't make sense to me right now, and I feel as though I must be misreading that.

Comment: So, if I initialize the grabber outside the main, as static, could it solve the problem? I am not sure why the initialization affects on the call of the grab method.

Comment: It's hard to say, lets assume the class didn't expect you to initialize it the way you have; it's not clearly documented what can and can't be passed to initialize it. So I look at: https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/IPCameraFrameGrabber.java?r=0e399872bfeb3824e975b3c575ad3a0a41027dee and its line 105 isn't even something that would throw an exception. Can you start by updating your dependency on this library?

Comment: There's code in the start method commented as "fragile" and there's stuff in the grabBufferedImage method grab calls that may throw this. I'm trying to help, but your problem is likely specific to the built in expectations of this library you're using, and a mismatch with what your IP camera is actually doing that didn't get tested by the original author(s).

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer, it is going to help me a lot. I will check the code of the class and modify if necessary. But, I have a last question, the code is maybe crashing because it expects another lenght. But, in that case, why does not fail at start and it does when it is running like 2-3 hours?. Thank you very much!.

Comment: @ManuelJoaquín You're right, in reading through the libraries I lost track of the exact issue, that is more odd that after a few hours you get this npe. BTW your url looks like an Axis camera url. Is it? That would remove the whole part of my answer about the web server. Okay Axis cams have Boa web server in firmware < 5.70 and apache web server in those 5.70 and above. Now I happen to have tired an axis v 5.50 with videolan.org's vlc. The stream closes after a 3-4 hours. Maybe it's just the camera?

Comment: Exactly, I am using an axis camera. Mmm, I did not know about the stream closes. That reason seems so reasonable. I guess the solution will be to make a program that opens a new stream every 2 hours to avoid that. I will post the results as soon as I have them!. Thank you very much for the tip, I did not think about it!

Comment: @ManuelJoaquín So I noticed on an axis camera that I have some 4 simultaneous users allowed. So if I open a stream with VLC using that URL right, and then browse to the viewer page 4 times, that's when it closes the "oldest" vlc stream, even though the other browser viewers had already closed and the VLC one had not.